# What is bitcoind.pid?

Tags: bitcoin-core

The file bitcoind.pid is mentioned on ["Running Bitcoin" wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin), but it's not explained on the wiki. What does that file do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't it the file containing (the current running instance of) bitcoin's pid,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier#Pidfile?